# Problem! Add a .tiff image in my iOS4 app

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimage, tiff

I use Adobe Photoshop,created a .tiff image.
Then I attach this image to an UIImageView.

Code Like:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.tiff"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

But,the image is not completely displayed.It's very rough and lost many details!

How can I deal with it?

Comment: The most supported file-type to use in iOS-apps are PNGs. You should use those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to Photoshop why would you choose to save a TIFF?

PNGs are the fastest and most supported image format on the iPhone, save it as a PNG instead!

Comment: Yes,but when I 'save as' a PNG format,Adobe Photoshop can't check the 'alpha channel' check box,It will lose information.

Comment: That's a problem with your Photoshop, not with the PNG file format; PNGs can definitely have alpha! Try going to File->'save for web & devices' and choosing png-24 from the dropdown on the right. This will save a copy of your file in PNG format.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the assertion that PNGs are the "fastest image format" on the iPhone?

Comment: Yep : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html - search for 'use the png format for images' - it's a bullet point about halfway down the page.